# where do i put the [Scringo initWithAppId:@"" completion:nil];

Tags: ios, sidebar, scringo

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Scringo/scringo.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;

    [Scringo initWithAppId:@"" completion:nil];

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

--

Is this the correct spot? the sidebar doesn't slide out in the emulator and I'm not getting any errors?… help

Comment: Putting code after the `return` statement is pointless. It will never be reached.

Comment: Then where should i put it ? when i put it over the return yes the app just crashes...

Comment: I have no idea what the line is supposed to or where it should be called but try putting it before the call to `return`.

Comment: just tried it before the return and it just crashes but when i take it out it runs just fine

Comment: Try finding documentation on Scringo. Perhaps its documentation tells you how to use it.

Comment: Init Scringo in your code

Open up your AppDelegate.m file and add the following line to the imports section:

#import <Scringo/Scringo.h>
Then add the following inside your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

[Scringo initWithAppId:@"YOUR_SCRINGO_APP_ID" completion:nil];

Comment: You said it crashes when you put it before the return. What is the crash message ?

Answer (score 0):

Use before return statement,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    [Scringo initWithAppId:@"YOUR_SCRINGO_APP_ID" completion:nil];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;


}
```